# Link2SD working issues

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, partitions, link2sd, ext3

I have installed the [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) application on my Samsung Galaxy Ace, everything is in place, now I dont understand how it works. I have allotted 1GB of space to my second `ext3` partition, I have 2 doubts:

1. Whenever I link my application, those space does not gets deducted from internal memory, I checked in *Settings → Manage Application*
2. When I move the application to SD card, still I have some space occupied in internal memory

I don't understand the exact use of Link2SD: if I allotted 1GB of space for the apps, then why my internal space is being used -- and if Link2SD does work like this only, then I would better use force move application using `adb shell`, which even does not require rooting. Can anyone please clarify my doubts, and let me know how can I use *Link2SD*, so that everything is moved to SD Card and nothing remains in internal memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application files consist of apk, dex, lib and data files. Link2sd can only move the first three types of files to your SD card. Program like Google+ has huge data files so even after using link2sd they take up precious space of internal memory.

When you move app to sd, only the apk file(in Android 2.2) and only the apk and lib files (in Android 2.3) are moved.

Comment: Then how can i retain my internal storage, and use external storage for the apps. is there anything in Link2SD to do that

Comment: Nope, link2sd can't link data as of now. You have to use data2sd for that.