# link2sd doesnot work please help

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, internal-storage, sd-card, link2sd

Link2sd not working on my rooted phone please help.
trying from 2 weeks. having Android 4.2 jellybean. it says Mount script cannot be created. no such file or directory.

Comment: No its not duplicate because i have downloaded it from Google play store. Please tell me another reason or sollution.

Comment: You can take a look at the related links on the right, both here and in the other link I provided. Also take a look at [link2sd working issues](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19684/link2sd-working-issues). Also, a search turned up [mount script cannot be created. no such file or directory](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68130/mount-script-cannot-be-created-mount-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I had read the given answers before also but i cant find my answers. Its not working. I have increase my internal memory before also but that time no problems arrived but now its not happening. Please help.

Comment: I will ask you the same question that is in the [mount script cannot be created](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68130/mount-script-cannot-be-created-mount-no-such-file-or-directory). What did you use to create the partitions?

Comment: I had used mini tool partition wizard on computer to partition my sd card.

Comment: Since you have to partition and format some as ext4/swap, i would suggest a LiveCD of linux and use GParted. windows doesn't know how to do anything with those partition types, so I would not trust anything on windows creating them. You will have problems like this.

Comment: I had used an application called Aparted(an application to manage partitions on android) also. It also detected that the partition is ext2 and its working correctly but link 2 sd dont detect that partition. Not only this, i had tried every partitions except fat16,fat32, and swap in my second partition but it also didnt work. Please help.

Comment: Please somebody help. My phone has low internal memory. So i cant install much games, apps or softwares.

Comment: You should edit your question with all the additional information instead of listing them in the comments. This way your question becomes more readable and attracts more potential answers.